# How to create a type that extract all methods from a class in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a class `Foo`

```
class Foo {
  bar(){
     // anything
  }

  baz() {
    // anything
  }
}
```

How can I create a type `ExtractMethods` that will receive a class and return an interface or a type with the class methods?

e.g.

```
type FooMethod = ExtractMethods<Foo> // => { bar(): void; baz(): void; }
```

I know one common comment to this questions will be "Why don't you just create a interface for `Foo` and use that interface you created?"

But in the case I want to solve, `Foo` isn't a class I created, but a third party class. I could create an interface for `Foo`, but it would never reflect perfectly the methods, in case the class changes in the future with updates I would need to also update the interface and this is something I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: It helps if your code example shows some use cases and edge cases, since right now `type ExtractMethods<T> = T` would work for your example.   Anyway, does [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7K4nN) work for you? As far as I know you cannot distinguish methods (which exist on the class prototype) from function-valued properties (which tend to exist on the instance) so the use cases really drive whether what you want is easy / hard / impossible.

Comment: @jcalz that sounds perfect. I had no idea that it's not possible to distinguish methods from function properties. but for me, that's ok

Comment: @jcalz if you want, please add that as an answer

Comment: I wonder if there is a sneaky way to distinguish methods from function-valued properties, using bivariance of method parameters? I guess it wouldn't be reliable because not all methods/functions have parameters.

Comment: @kaya3 Yeah, if you have method parameters you can probably do a bivariance check somehow, but as far as I know there's no good way to generalize this.  As far as I know mapped types always turn methods into func-props.  I'd love to be proven wrong, though!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's write a type function `PickMatching<T, V>` which takes an object type `T` and a property value type `V` and evaluates to another object type only those properties of `T` whose property types are assignable to `V`.  This is straightforward if we use [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type PickMatching<T, V> =
    { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: T[K] }
```

By mapping a key to `never` we are essentially omitting the property from the mapped type.  Then we can express `ExtractMethods<T>` by picking all function-valued properties from `T`:

```
type ExtractMethods<T> = PickMatching<T, Function>;
```

This produces the following results:

```
class Foo {
    bar() { }
    baz() { }
    notAMethod = 123;
    funcProp = () => 10;
}

type FooMethod = ExtractMethods<Foo>
/* type FooMethod = {
    bar: () => void;
    baz: () => void;
    funcProp: () => number;
} */
```

As you see, the `number`-typed `notAMethod` is not present in `FooMethod`.  The methods `bar()` and `baz()` appear in `FooMethod` as desired.  Importantly, the function-typed `funcProp` is *also* present in `FooMethod`.  The type system cannot reliably distinguish a *method* from a *function-valued property*.  The main difference is whether or not the member exists on the instance directly or on the class prototype, but the type system treats class instances and class prototypes as the same type.

That's really the best you can do to implement `ExtractMethods` generally.

---

On the other hand, if you want to do it just for a *particular* class like `Foo` and can drop down from the type level to the value level, you can use the fact that the compiler understands that [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) an instance of a class into a new object will only give you the instance properties:

```
const spreadFoo = { ... new Foo() };
/* const spreadFoo: {
  notAMethod: number;
  funcProp: () => number;
} */
```

and from *that* you can compute `FooMethod` (assuming that you don't have any non-method prototype members):

```
type FooMethod = Omit<Foo, keyof typeof spreadFoo>;
/* type FooMethod = {
  bar: () => void;
  baz: () => void;
} */
```

But it depends on your use cases whether or not this sort of approach is feasible.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBABQJYGMDWBZAhmFALJAOwHMAeAFQBo4A1APjgF5Q5W4BvOAbQGk4i4aGBAD2AMzjk4WAM6TeAXTgwAHmBiEAJnJpwA-HD4AuOIRgA3GACcFJ8orgBfUKEiw4AUTVWsKMBhgwPBFtCgZGRFRMHHwiMio4ADEAV0I-JBFCOgBuFxBQFAAbWTlEkREOFjYAIywrAAoASg4nKtZagC8mlucQNlMRMABBAKCQpjgARgAmAGZcvrYxVJQEKxEoCe7GBkmABgXe12h4MpFR4M0JrzAfPwuQmVIzulAAegAqODdT8oeriLsNpwWpWEzbBjmERITQLfqdcHNHZwKEwuFLFZrDaIpgMQjJAC21WshzgHzeeUIWAJMBkUF88AAEgSCZVFqwUJkZGA4HSrDAsJozhNOAA6cWmGAAdyS5W6jnRrE+cE5hG5vKg-MFZxMQPZbEIgxGgUuJnxRJJwNYyzSWKgOOR5uJVkVTjJFP1P1l5xN4wiAHkCUgwM9ytQhKIJD9xBqtULyjlgcqvWd-iKrSC6g7IdDYRmEXAISjc67HO68o4gA)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](https://www.piotrl.net/typescript-condition-subset-types/), I came up with the following solution ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=62&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeAoa0BmB7XAFAJRoC+m0ARmAE7FkUBet0AvNAMwDc656SATwAO8aAGUArpVjD4AHgBCkeABpoAYVwA7ACYBLJHu0A+NtAAKe4AGtFytRixYA2gGl4A6Hq3RrH3NjQShDwALoAXEHKbh6h0PAAHkjwujCaugZGPgD80O6ekVrwAG7wNLzOfgIBUSGhxjz8stAAsvBIABa4OhAA8logAnKwpuyS0rLDavSsphJa1lq4AO5aDehNInBmljbDiEhqVTVtnd19A0MIyMbGG8DayNDJT+yopNCQcI0vSAB01BoXGgAHoQdAQPAAOZgED8A5-PC4YFgiHQ2Hw5B-ZhA0Hg8w0XAiGiCaAAchxZOgOlwiGgSxQiT0T20z2aZNgZL+BAATBwOABOIjoIA)):

```js
class Test {
  foo() {}
  bar() {}
  zar = 3;
}

type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, {
    [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
}[keyof Base]>;

type MethodsOnly<T> = SubType<T, () => unknown>;

type T = Pick<Test, keyof MethodsOnly<Test>>

const test = {} as T;

test.bar; // legal
test.foo; // legal
test.zar; // Property 'zar' does not exist on type 'T'.(2339)
```