# Typescript utils for class methods

Tags: typescript, types

How can I use [Typescript utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) to retrieve classe's methods, so we able to do something like this

```
this.myClass[someMethod as Methods<MyClass>]()
```

this approach will consider methods and properties as well

```
this.myClass[someMethod as keyof typeof MyClass]()
```

causing an error because not all keys of MyClass are callable

Comment: use the type form of `extends` (not inheritance)

Comment: There's no built-in utility type for this; you'd have to write one yourself.  I usually write `KeysMatching<T, V>` as shown in the linked q/a, and then you can use `KeysMatching<MyClass, ()=>any>`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaZpEm).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70427637/how-to-create-a-type-that-extract-all-methods-from-a-class-in-typescript better duplicate